# Why doesn't my program wait like I need it to?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

Ok pretty much what I am trying to do is have my program wait a predetermined amount of times then move the character to another spot on the grid (which is notated by the "panel_x" and "panel_y" variables). Instead it waits and then moves the character around every frame...Im not sure what I am doing wrong. I believe I need a coroutine, but I may be wrong.

```
//How I am calling the coroutine
void Update()
    {
       if(HP != 0)
       { 
       StartCoroutine(Wait());
       }
    }

//The Coroutine I need to run to move my character
//around...I need this to run until the character's
//hp reaches 0.
IEnumerator Wait()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            //I need it to wait...  
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
            //Then move the character to another
            //grid...
            panel_x = Random.Range(1, 4);
            panel_y = Random.Range(1, 4);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update runs on every frame. What's happening here is that you're calling Wait() on every frame which will run multiple instances in an infinite loop.

I believe what you're trying to do is change the x and y values every 3 seconds.
If so, try something like this.

```
float timer = 0.0f;
void Update()
{
    if (HP != 0)
    {
       timer += Time.deltaTime;
       if (timer >= 3)
       {
           panel_x = Random.Range(1, 4);
           panel_y = Random.Range(1, 4);
           timer = 0;
       }
    }
}
```

Time.deltaTime returns the time passed between frames so it can be used as a timer by summing it every frame. When 3 seconds has passed, we reset the timer to 0 and run our method.

Comment: Thanks! Someone on my Twitter told me to just put StartCoroutine in the start method which worked, but this was suggested to me numerous times so I will use this next time I need something like this done!

Answer (score 0):

Did you modify that `HP` ever after? If HP is not 0, then the `StartCoroutine(Wait())` will be called every time `Update()` is executed. That is why you get the weird result.

Answer (score -1):

Your function doesn't seem to take any parameters, so I can provide you other method like `Invoke` as an alternative.

`Invoke(x, y)` executes a function after a certain amount of seconds delay. In your case for example:

```
void Update(){
    if(HP != 0)
        Invoke("MoveChar", 3); //execute MoveChar() after 3 seconds
}

MoveChar(){
    panel_x = Random.Range(1,4);
    panel_y = Random.Range(1,4);
}
```

Just for your info, there is also `InvokeRepeating(x, y, z)` which maybe you won't need in this case.
It repeats every z seconds after function x being called with y delay.

```
void Start(){ 
    //execute MoveChar() after 3 seconds and call the
    //function again after 0.5 seconds repeatedly
    InvokeRepeating("MoveChar", 3, 0.5);
}

MoveChar(){
    panel_x = Random.Range(1,4);
    panel_y = Random.Range(1,4);
}
```